# how to login and configure LinkedIn and Twitter SDK in android

Tags: android, sdk, linkedin-api

Can any one suggest any complete Latest tutorial link for successful integration of LinkedIn sdk. it shows robolectric plugin Id not found error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth please check this once

Comment: any luck with this yet? I am having the same error

Comment: No,Not Yet. I used LinkedInj [link](https://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) for linkedIn Login.

Answer (score 0):

- It's recommended to use official [Mobile SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk) for LinkedIn android integration.and the [developer documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs).
- Use [Fabric](https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android) for Twitter integration

  **You can find API documentation too :)**

Visit following link to get [document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvhmlsawaz7njsk/LinkedInIntegration.doc?dl=0) that i have prepared for LinkedIn integration i hope this may help you with  a lead.

Comment: I used web view with linkedInj library for LinkedIn Login,But still want to know LinkedIn Login with official Mobile SDK which shows robolectric plugin Id not found error.can you explain steps to install and configure in android studio api 22. Thank You @Anoop

Comment: If your going through the document's carefully you can really do it quickly..tell me if any further doubt..

Comment: Ok,Thank you for prompt reply.